# Cannot see folders sub folders and files in Vs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started using Visual Studio Code Version 1.15.1 and for some reason, after closing all the folders in the navigation explorer side bar, I cannot get it back to display the folder structure and files in the project, even after closing and reopening. The files and folders are available and I can see them fine in OSX Sierra. Also the VS code window title shows the name of the project.

[image: Please see the attached image]

Comment: Did you try Re-opening the folder in VS Code again?

Comment: Yes I did, but I get the same. Drag and drop does the same. The only thing that will bring it back is renaming the root folder in osx  and opening it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it back by right clicking on the sidebar "Explorer" header, and selecting "Folders". See the gif here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32962#issuecomment-324866098

This has confused several people so we've decided to remove the ability to hide the "Folders" view. Continuing discussion on the general UI is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31485

Comment: I would suggest making it clearer. Right click anywhere in the explorer should give the ability to redisplay the tree structure.